# сделать connect между главным окном и вторым потоком из диалогового окна

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Как сделать connect между вторым потоком и главным окном из диалогового окна?

Из главного окна mainwindow перешел в manualsetting. В окне manualsetting создал второй поток

```
sensormanager = new(SensorManager);
QThread* pThread=new(QThread);
sensormanager->moveToThread(pThread);
QObject::connect(pThread, SIGNAL(started()), sensormanager, SLOT(slotAutoModeBalancer()));
QObject::connect(sensormanager, SIGNAL(finished()), pThread, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(pThread, SIGNAL(finished()), pThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
pThread->start();

// Нужно принять сигнал в главном окне
QObject::connect(sensormanager, SIGNAL(signalInfoAuto()), 
                 ???????, SLOT(slot()));
```

Мне нужно передать сигнал из второго потока в главное окно. 
Сделать коннект нужно из диалогового окна `manualsetting`.

Comment: _Сделать конект нужно из диалогового окна manualsetting_ как это понять?

Comment: Вопрос в том как сделать связь сигнал--слот из диалогового окна (название диалогового окна manualsetting)  с главным окном. Мне чтобы сделать связь нужно знать указатель на главное окно. А у меня в диалоговом окне manualsetting его нет. И что указать при создание connect в поле object 2 не знаю.

Comment: А диалоговое окно создается не в методе главного окна?

Comment: Если описать полную конструкцию то получится. Главное окно ---> диалоговое окно ---> создание второго потока в диалоговом окне ---> создание связи сигнал слот второй поток главное окно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ManualSetting : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

    ManualSetting() : QDialog() {
        // Создаем потока
        ...
        // Передаем сигнал из потока, пробрасывая его при помощи сигнала диалога 
        // Новье Qt 5+
        connect(sensormanager, &SensorManager::signalInfoAuto, this, &ManualSetting::signalFromThread);
        // Старье Qt 4.7.8
        connect(sensormanager, SIGNAL(signalInfoAuto()), 
                this, SIGNAL(signalFromThread()));
    }

signals:
    void signalFromThread(<Согласованные с сигналом потока, аргументы>);
}
```

Главное окно:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    void showDialog() {
        ManualSetting manualsetting;
        // Для Qt 4.7.8 (Qt < 5 )
        connect(&manualsetting, SIGNAL(signalsFromThread()),
                this, SLOT(processThreadSignal()));
        // Или для новья Qt 5+
        connect(&manualsetting, &ManualSetting::signalsFromThread, 
                this, &MainWindow::processThreadSignal);
        ...
        manualsetting.exec();
    }
slots:
    void processThreadSignal() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Дополнение. Если у вас мегавложенность диалогов, то делаете тоже самое, то есть соединяете сигналы внутренних диалогов с внешними, по цепочке.

Comment: Нет вы объединили поток и ManualSetting. 
Попытаюсь еще проще спросить. Если описать полную конструкцию то получится. При старте попадаем в главное окно ---> диалоговое окно 1 ---> диалоговое окно 2 ---> диалоговое окно N. Хочу передать сигнал из диалогового окна N в главное окно по средствам сигналов и слотов. Как это сделать какие есть решения?

Comment: @zhilenkov нет, я пробросил сигнал наружу. Обратите внимание, я соединил сигнал потока с сигналом диалогового окна

Comment: Вы соединили сигнал потока с диалоговым окном ManualSetting. Я хочу соединить сигнал с главным окном. Из главного окна открыт ManualSetting. Получается сигнал должен пройти через ManualSetting и попасть в главное окно.

Comment: @zhilenkov это естесственная операция. В чем тут проблема? Компилятор соединит эти вызовы напрямую, если вы укажете последним аргументов в коннекте Qt::DirectConnection, а по умолчанию вы не увидите разницы вообще.

Comment: Так мне нужно еще указать object2 в connect?  У меня qt4.7.8. Я не могу сделать вот так &MainWindow::processThreadSignal

Comment: Я правильно понимаю с помощью connect(manualsetting, SIGNAL(signalsFromThread()),
                this, SLOT(processThreadSignal())); можно передать сигнал из второго потока созданного в диалоговом окне manualsetting в главное окно? Просто мне не ясно от куда у вас указатель manualsetting где вы его храните ?

Comment: @zhilenkov у вас в вопросе нет ничего про то, что такое manualsetting (объект, или указатель). Вот сейчас подправил, теперь это просто объект, соответственно исправил коннект. И да, можно (нужно, раз уж у вас такая архитектура) передавать сигнал таким способом

Comment: У меня ещё сложнее. Попытаюсь объяснить. У меня промышленный пк. С маленьким дисплеем 640 на 480. При запуски программы стартует главное окно из него есть переходы диалоговые окна. По типу диалоговое окно меню, ручное управление, график, и т.д.  Открыл диалоговое меню. Из меню перешёл в настройки запустил второй поток  передал через сигналы и слоты данные второго потока в главное окно. И закрыл диалог меню. Но не знаю как это сделать как передавать сигналы и слоты при работе с множеством диалоговых окон да и ещё каждое окно имеет равнозначные права по управлению.

Comment: @zhilenkov закройте текущий вопрос и задайте этот (из комментария) отдельно, потому что он больше по архитектуре, а текущий чисто технический

Comment: Хорошо так и сделаю.